# Oracle SQL: Stored procedure - object invalid

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I was just about to create a store procedure and it worked so far.
(For learning purposes I want to hand a credit card number over to a stored procedure which should return the associated customer identification number.)
But when I wanted to test this procedure using

```sql
BEGIN CC_TO_CID(:p1, :p2); 
END;
```

(the input data was submitted via a dialogue of my SQL IDE)
it just returned:

> SQL Error [6550][65000]: ORA-06550: Row 1, Column 7: 
>  PLS-00905
>   Object xyz.CC_TO_CID is invalid
>  ORA-06550: Row 1, Column 7: 
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

This basically means that my stored procedure isn't well formatted but I really don't have any clue.

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CC_TO_CID(in_cc_nr IN NUMBER(16,0), out_cid OUT NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
SELECT PM.CUSTOMER_ID INTO cid FROM "2_PAYMENT_M" PM, 
"2_CREDITCARD" CC
WHERE CC.CC_NR=in_cc_nr AND CC.PAYMENT_M_NR=PM.PAYMENT_M_NR;
END;
```

My table structure with some test data:

```
Table: "2_CREDITCARD"
       CC_NR         PAYMENT_M_NR       NAME       CVV         EXPIRES        
 ------------------ -------------- -------------- ----- --------------------- 
  5307458270409047              1   Haley Harrah    52   2019-11-01 00:00:00  



Table: "2_PAYMENT_M"
  PAYMENT_M_NR   CUSTOMER_ID         CREATED         TRANSACTION_LIMIT  
 -------------- ------------- --------------------- ------------------- 
             1           100   2018-01-21 00:00:00               1.000
```

Thanks in advance!
I appreciate any useful hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have seen an error when you compiled the procedure, but it would probably have been quite generic. Your client may support `show errors`, or you can query the `user_errors` view to see the details.

You can’t give a size or precision restriction for [the data type of a formal parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/formal-parameter-declaration.html#GUID-5BA8E033-96B9-439A-A4FC-4844FEC14AD8) to a function or procedure, so `NUMBER(10,0)` should just be `NUMBER`; and you have got the name of the argument wrong in your `into` clause.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CC_TO_CID(in_cc_nr IN NUMBER, out_cid OUT NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
  SELECT PM.CUSTOMER_ID
  INTO out_cid
  FROM "2_PAYMENT_M" PM
  JOIN "2_CREDITCARD" CC
  ON CC.PAYMENT_M_NR=PM.PAYMENT_M_NR
  WHERE CC.CC_NR=in_cc_nr;
END;
```

I’ve switched to ANSI join syntax because... well, just because. Untested as I don’t have your tables; if it still gets errors then check `user_errors` again.

Comment: You're my hero. It just tested it and itworked great!
Thanks man.

Comment: Wow would have never realized this. Thanks!!